# PHP comment form

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms, comments

I have a comment form that I have created. It gets the id from the database and prints out the data that goes with that id, but it also prints out the information into the form. How can I get a blank form, so that the user can add a comment to the record?

This the code for the form:

```
<form method="post" action="pv.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID']?>&action=<?php echo $form_action ?>">
    <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>
        <p>
            <label for="cname">Date Of Birth</label>  *
            <input id="cname" name="dateofbirth" class="required date"  value="<?php echo $row['Date_Of_Birth']?>" />  (eg 1978.11.11)
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="cgender">Gender</label>   *
            <input type="radio"
                   name="gender"
                   value="Male"
                   <?php if($row['Gender']=='male'){echo 'checked';}?>/>
                   Male
            <input type="radio"
                   name="gender"
                   value="Female"
                   <?php if($row['Gender']=='female'){echo 'checked';}?>/> Female </td>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="curl">Title</label>   *
            <select name="title"   id="title"  class="required">
                <option value="">Please Select</option>
                <option value="Mr" <?php if($row['Title']=='Mr'){echo 'selected';}?>>Mr</option>
                <option value="Ms" <?php if($row['Title']=='Ms'){echo 'selected';}?>>Ms</option>
                <option value="Mrs" <?php if($row['Title']=='Mrs'){echo 'selected';}?>>Mrs</option>
                <option value="Miss" <?php if($row['Title']=='Miss'){echo 'selected';}?>>Miss</option>
                <option value="Other" <?php if($row['Title']=='Other'){echo 'selected';}?>>Other</option>
                </select>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="ccomment">First Name</label>     *
            <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $row['First_Name']?>" maxlength="50" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="cemail">Last Name</label> *
            <input id="cemail" type="text" name="lastname"
                   value="<?php echo $row['Last_Name']?>" maxlength="75" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="ccomment">Address 1</label>*
            <input type="text" name="address1"
                   value="<?php echo $row['Address_Line_1']?>" maxlength="50" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="ccomment">Address 2</label>
            <input type="text" name="address2"
                   value="<?php echo $row['Address_Line_2']?>" maxlength="50" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="ccomment">City</label>*
            <input type="text" name="city"
                   value="<?php echo $row['City']?>"  maxlength="50" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="ccomment">Postcode</label>*
            <input type="text" name="postcode"
                   value="<?php echo $row['Postcode']?>" maxlength= "10" />  (eg LE5 5QE)
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="ccomment">Contact No</label>*
            <input type="text" name="contactno"
                   value="<?php echo $row['Contact_No']?>" maxlength= "12" />  (eg 077448825723)
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="ccomment">Email</label>*
            <input type="text" name="email"
                   value="<?php echo $row['Email']?>" maxlength= "40"/>  (eg info@example.com)
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="ccomment">Comment</label>
            <textarea rows="10" cols="30" name="note"
                      maxlength= "500"><?php echo $row['Additional_Comment']?></textarea>
        </p>

        <p>
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </p>

        <p>
            <a href='pv.php'>Main Page</a>
       </p>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

This is the code for printing out the data on the page:

```
if($_GET['action'] == 'comment') {
    $form_action = 'comment_ok';
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM project_data WHERE id='$id'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    echo'<b>';
        echo $row['Date_Of_Birth'];
        echo '&nbsp&nbsp';
        echo $row['Gender'];
        echo '&nbsp&nbsp';
        echo $row['Title'];
        echo '&nbsp&nbsp';
        echo $row['First_Name'];
        echo '&nbsp&nbsp';
        echo $row['Last_Name'];
        echo '&nbsp&nbsp';
        echo $row['Address_Line_1'];
        echo '&nbsp&nbsp';
        echo $row['Address_Line_2'];
        echo '&nbsp&nbsp';
        echo $row['City'];
        echo '&nbsp&nbsp';
        echo $row['Postcode'];
        echo '&nbsp&nbsp';
        echo $row['Contact_No'];
        echo '&nbsp&nbsp';
        echo $row['Email'];
        echo '&nbsp&nbsp';
        echo $row['Additional_Comment'];
    echo '</b>';
}
```

And a snippet of the code I am using to send the id to the form:

```
echo "<td><a href='pv.php?action=edit&id=" . $row['ID'] .
     "'>Edit</a>&nbsp&nbsp<a href='pv.php?action=delete_ok&id=" . $row['ID'] .
     "'>Delete</a>&nbsp&nbsp**<a href='pv.php?action=comment&id=" . $row['ID'] .
     "'>Comment</a></td>"**;
echo "</tr>";
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What is your question? Is something not working?

Comment: I have a comment page for each individual record, when I click it the record data prints at the top, but I want a blank form, not one with the data showing at the top and in the form. I want to know how to show a blank form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want one page that allows the user to fill in a blank form, see a filled out form and update a form.

You can do the blank form or filled form by checking if an id exist, like this:

```php
<?
    if (isset(id)) // Here you can check if the id exists, which means you will be doing an update to the SQL query
        echo'
        <form method="post" action="pv.php?id=' . $row['ID'] . '&action=' . $form_action . '">

            <!-- Your form here with values -->
            e.g. <label for="cemail">Last Name</label> *
            <input id="cemail" type="text" name="lastname" value="' . $row['Last_Name'] . '" maxlength="75" />
        </form>';

        // Put your SQL update here to take the values from the above form
    }
    elseif (!isset(id)) // Here there is no id so you will want to insert
    {
        echo'
        <form method="post" action="pv.php?id=' . $row['ID'] . '&action=' . $form_action . '">
            <!-- Your form here with values -->
            e.g. <label for="cemail">Last Name</label> *
            <input id="cemail" type="text" name="lastname" maxlength="75" /> // No value here because will insert new record
        </form>';

        // Put your SQL insert here to create a new record
    }
?>
```

If you may want the user to be able to add a new comment entirely rather than editing the one already associated with their id, I think you would have to do this by giving them the option to add another comment. To do this, I would create a new table and then insert the comments into that, so you have one table, *example_users* with the user information, and then another table, *user_comments*, with the user comments, for example:

#### Table *example_users*

```
id = 1
fname=Joe
lname=Bloggs
email=jbloggs@example.com
```

#### Table *user_comments*

```
id=1
user_id=1
comment=Comment will be saved here
```

This way, any user can have any number of comments. You could render this on the page by using a *foreach* statement to render a text box with all their existing comments and then have a blank one at the end for any new ones. Then they can edit any comment and add a new comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the form to be blank, then just set the value attribute to empty. E.g value=''. Except for the id field.

Comment: I have one form the controls three links, one for edit, one to insert a new entry, and one for a comment. the insert one is blank, because I'm sending no id, the edit one is filled in, because I am sending the id, and comment is the same, but it shouldn't be filled.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you echo stuff when an id has been sent. So two options: do not send the id, or ignore it. BTW, you've got quite a vulnerability going on here: `$id=$_GET['id']; $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM project_data WHERE id='$id'");` You should consider the risks of [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Your form fields are not filled because you are sending the id, they are filled because you set the value attribute - value=<?php echo $row[...]; ?>. If you leave it this way value="", then it will be empty.

Comment: yeah but like i said, i have one form which controls three different parts, is there no way i can use one form to control the comment part, still sending the id to print the data, but having a blank form?